# Guardar <Integer,Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> numa coleção

Tags: java, array, hashmap

O que eu pretendo é fazer uma associação de dados da seguinte forma:

```
(<<Integer>, <Integer>, ArrayList<Integer>)
```

Tentei criar um `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>>` o problema é que esqueci-me que as chaves têm de ser únicas e eu preciso de ter por vezes valores iguais.

Ex: (1,1,{1,2,3,4})
    (1,2,{1,3})

Qual será a melhor forma de conseguir agregar esses dados?

Comment: e se criares uma classe com esses valores não dá?

Comment: Não experimentei nem sei bem como faço. Uma classe que guarda esses valores? Os valores não são estáticos.

Comment: Isso de os valores não serem estáticos não tem importância, porque atualizavas a classe através dos get e set, mas ias ter o mesmos problema das chaves(agora pensando), porque como ias destingir a classe x da classe y, se os valores que comparas são iguais? tens a certeza que não consegues ter uma chave unica?

Comment: é possível as duas chaves serem iguais em outros casos exemplo: `(<<1>, <1>, ArrayList<Integer>)`, `(<<1>, <2>, ArrayList<Integer>)` , `(<<1>, <1>, ArrayList<Integer>)`: tipo neste caso o exemplo 1 é igual ao 3 ?

Comment: É igual mas têm de ser inseridos os 3 exemplos na BD. Usando o HashMap ele não me duplicava os dados e eu preciso de conseguir duplicá-los

Comment: pois com o `HasMap` ele substitui o mais antigo pelo novo quando são iguais, logo não dá... Esses dados vao ser alterados isto é, depois de estar na colecção precisa atualizados?

Comment: Não, depois de estarem na coleção, são enviados logo para a BD e não se liga mais a esses valores. Simplesmente depois posso fazer outra coleção e enviar outros dados, mas estando na coleção, eles só são enviados para a BD mais nada

Comment: O que eu faria, @Hugo, seria criar uma classe a parte para suportar os dados que você precise, e junto com esses dados implementar uma variavel `id`, pois assim na hr de persistir, com a manipulação adequada, vc conseguiria inserir objetos iguais mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução possível é criares a classe onde agregas esses dados, para depois criares uma lista de todos os objectos dessa classe.

```
//crias a classe com todos os dados que o teu objeto precisa
public class myNewObjecto
{
    private integer num1;
    private integer num2;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listNumeros;

    //crias os get/set

    /
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         //implementar o hashCode
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         //implementar o equals   
    }

}
```

Crias a `list` de guarda os teu objectos:

```
private ArrayList<myNewObjecto> listmyNewObjecto;
```

Depois adicionas o dados ao teu objecto:

```
//se criares o construtor na class fazes:
myNewObjecto obj = new myNewObjecto(1,2,listaInteiros);
//senão usas os set´s
myNewObjecto obj = new myNewObjecto();
obj.setNum1(1);
obj.setNum2(2);
obj.set(listNumeros);

//adicionas o objeto a tua lista
listNumeros.add(obj);
```

Comment: A questão é que os valores que quero adicionar à lista ou objeto criado, estão numa classe e provêm de valores de checkboxes

Comment: Sim mas qual é a tua duvida ao certo? ir buscar os valores a checkbox ou por serem em classes diferentes?

Comment: É por ser em classes diferentes. Basta colocar a CheckBox como pública para ter acesso na nova classe?

Comment: Faça de tudo para evitar usar acessos publicos em propriedades.  O Checkbox tem algum evento que é ativado quando mudado, ou quando um formulario é enviado por exemplo? Se sim, é só no ter uma referencia fixa de um objeto da nova classe, e na hora do evento, setar o novo valor.

Comment: **Não** essa nao é a logica que deves seguir(apesar de funcionar) o tua nova classe `myNewObjecto` vai ser uma classe sozinha(como penso que já deve estar), na outra classe onde tens as checkBox, crias o objeto, ou a lista. E crias também o get que te vai devolver essa lista para a outra classe... Nao sei se deu para perceber, não é nada fácil de explicar assim

Comment: @HugoMachado Conseguiste por a funcionar?

Comment: Vou tentar agora, tive de volta de outras coisas. Uma questão, pode ser uma Inner Class?

Comment: Se percebi bem, acho que não, porque tu vais precisar dela em varias classes.

Comment: Então vou criar uma classe à parte. Dá para explicar brevemente o que é isso do HashCode e a implementação do equals?! Desculpe mas tou a aprender :D Agradeço desde já a disponibilidade para tal

Comment: Sem problemas, eu também estou a aprender logo a minha explicação pode não ser a melhor, mas resumido tanto o hashcode como o equals são usados para quando comparas os objectos e aconselho te a dares uma lida nisso, é mesmo muito importante, porque uma coisa e quando tens `(1).equals(1)` outra é quando tens `(conta).equals(conta)`, mais uma vez não consigo explicar por aqui, mas se usas o `Netbeans` (e quase de certeza que no eclipse também tem essa funcionalidades) ele cria isso automaticamente, não quero dizer que é exatamente o que tu precisas, mas dá para teres uma ideia...

Comment: Áhh já percebi a ideia :) tou a tentar fazer, qualquer coisa eu peço ajuda. No fim de adicionar os ojetos à minha lista, como é que consigo percorrer a lista e ir buscar cada elemento de cada objeto ?

Comment: Já consegui o que queria. Funcionou bem! Obrigado @jsantos1991 :D

Comment: porreiro... fico feliz que tenha conseguido...